# Google Books downloader for Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, pdf, google, downloaders

I want to download free Google books in pdf format.

Is there any Google Books downloading tool available for Ubuntu?

Comment: duplicate question , maybe this answer could help
http://askubuntu.com/questions/339927/download-google-books

Comment: @HanyAlsamman Not exact duplicate because I clarified "downloader" and however  http://askubuntu.com/q/339927 is closed as **unclear**!

Comment: check this tutorial http://www.pc-freak.net/blog/download-books-books-google-greasemonkey-google-books-downloader-script/

Comment: Two other solutions I found a while ago: [pysheng](https://code.google.com/p/pysheng/) and [getxbook](http://njw.me.uk/getxbook/). I would write a proper answer but I've never tried these out. So if you feel up to task, please feel free to include these tools in your own post.

Comment: @HanyAlsamman that answer doesn't come close to answering this OP's question.  and the tutorial you've linked to has a downloader that works only on windows and mac OSes.

Comment: pysheng only downloads the 35 first pages, no matter how many pages does the book have.
I don't know if this is a limitation imposed by google or by pysheng.

Answer (score 9):

Thanks to @Glutanimate for his comment to the OP.

[getxbook](http://njw.me.uk/getxbook/) makes a [good case](http://njw.me.uk/getxbook/comparison) for why it is the best option available.  I just installed it and used it to download [this book](https://books.google.com/books?id=3pK1-LxtFV4C&pg=PA230&lpg=PA230&dq=Dopamine%27s+influence+on+prefrontal+cortical+cognition:+actions+and+circuits+in+behaving+primates&source=bl&ots=SC2avDNa5H&sig=HLLwcAZSLoahLy5I8hkbvPPWW5o&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CC0Q6AEwAmoVChMItbKe0MqdxwIVVzSICh1WkAJM#v=onepage&q&f=false) with success.

getxbook comes with installation instructions (in the `INSTALL` file).  Once installed, it is run as follows:

```
$ getxbookgui
```

Alternatively, the command

```
$ getgbook book-id
```

can be used.  (The book ID is in the URL for the book.  For example, the ID for the book I downloaded is `3pK1-LxtFV4C`.)

If only a subset of pages is desired, use

```
$ getgbook -n book-id
```

And then enter the pages you want, one at a time, e.g.:

```
$ getgbook -n book-id
262
```

When I said the book was downloaded with success, I wasn't being totally honest.  For some reason, **getxbook missed a few pages that were available in the preview**.  To get these, I followed [these instructions](https://arbitweb.wordpress.com/2011/07/29/how-to-download-a-page-from-google-books/).

Note that the book is downloaded to a sub-directory of the current directory named with the book ID.  It is downloaded as a set of `.png` and/or `.jpg` files, one per page.  These can be converted to `.pdf` format as follows (after converting the `.jpg` files to `.png` files one by one):

```
$ convert *.png book.pdf
```

Note that if you intend to print this `.pdf` on paper, you may need to resize some of the individual images (so that they're all roughly the same size) before converting to the `.pdf`.  I used gimp to do this.

Comment: make: *** No rule to make target 'util.h', needed by 'getgbook.o'.  Stop.

PySheng worked for me instead.

Comment: you can use torify to assist downloading more pages on books that have a page download limit: "torify getgbook book-id"

Comment: The instructions to use chrome dev tools to download individual pages is out of date and no longer seems to work.

Answer (score 9):

There is a Python program called **`PySheng`** than did the job for me.

It's available on Github at https://github.com/tokland/pysheng

You can run the following commands to install it.

```
git clone https://github.com/tokland/pysheng
cd pysheng
sudo python setup.py install
```

Now PySheng will be available from the Termainl.

You can run **`pysheng-gui`** and **`pysheng`** from the terminal for the GUI and terminal version respectively.

```
pysheng-gui
```

[image: PySheng GUI for downloading from Google Books]

Comment: According to  `pysheng/readme.md`, the correct command for installation (and the one that worked for me) is `sudo python setup.py install`. - I have edited accordingly.

Comment: It is installed by default in the `home` directory. But then it can be moved anywhere and launched by executing `/pysheng/bin/pysheng-gui`. Path to that could be added into a launcher (`desktop` file) put in `~/.local/share/applications`.

Comment: import gtk.glade
ImportError: No module named glade   Its giving this error. I tried to follow the steps in [git hub](https://github.com/Hackerood/pysheng/issues/6) but I am unable to find /usr/share/pysheng/main.glade in line 362. In fact in the whole script there is no such line.

Comment: @Hirak Try this: sudo apt-get install git python-appindicator python-xdg python-pexpect python-gconf python-gtk2 python-glade2 libxxf86vm1